# SQL; Split a value up using sql in hive/hue

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, hue

needing some advice on splitting a number into a date timestamp, currently using Hue to query the hive db;

In a table I have a column that is used to capture a unique ref for a record.  The value looks like this;

```
219872021081000741
```

Contained within this is a date and time, I'm looking to extract (using sql) the date/time from this and have it as a column of its own.  Here is the breakdown of the number:

Based on the bold values from left to right is DD YYYY MM HHMM

**21** 987 **2021** **08** **1000** 741

regex
[0-3]?[0-9]{1}$ref[2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-9]{3}_"

Using sql, I want to assess the number then create a column that then formats it to DD-MM-YY HHMM as timestamp.  Have reviewed some posts, and trying out a few things, but not having much luck.  The other sticking point is the DD will not always be 2 values eg, if it was the 1st then it will be 1 not 01.

Trying to incorporate into the below. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
select *,
cast((UTC +(60*60*12)*1000)/1000 as TIMESTAMP) as `LocalTime`
from Table.Name
where 
   name rlike 'FieldValue.*'
```

**UPDATE: In a roundabout way I updated the sql to do a count of the value.**

- If it has 17 digits, then i know the day is anywhere from the 1st-9th
  so I tag it as 17.
- If it has 18 digits, then I know the day is anywhere from the 10h-endofmonth
- From here i use substring to return the day components, which I'll bring into a single field via concat or something along those lines.**

Here is the update sql, just need to figure out/get some guidance on how I now determine how to use the new column FieldCount eg it is 17, then         substring(FieldValue ,1,**1**) given its anything from the 1st-9th.  If its 18, then substring(FieldValue ,1,**2**) given its anything from the 10th up.

```
select *,
    cast((utc+(60*60*12)*1000)/1000 as TIMESTAMP) as `LocalTime`,
    case
    when FieldValue REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' then '17'
    when FieldValue REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' then '17'
    end FieldCount,
    substring(FieldValue ,6,4) as Years,
    substring(FieldValue ,1,1) as Days,
    substring(FieldValue ,10,2) as Months,
    substring(FieldValue ,12,2) as Hours,
    substring(FieldValue ,14,2) as Minut 
    from table.name
```

**New Update, I changed this now to separate based on case condition.  This basically separates out the value into separate fields.  Any ideas to concat based on alias field names?**

```
select
AField,
cast((UTC+(60*60*12)*1000)/1000 as TIMESTAMP) as `LocalTime`,
case when length(AField) = 18 then substring(AField,1,2)  else substring(AField,1,1) end Days,
case when length(AField) = 18 then substring(AField,10,2) else substring(AField,9,2) end Months,
case when length(AField) = 18 then substring(AField,6,4) else substring(AField,5,4) end years,
case when length(AField) = 18 then substring(AField,12,2) else substring(caseid,11,2) end Hours,
case when length(AField) = 18 then substring(AField,14,2) else  substring(AField,13,2) end minutes
from table.name
```

Comment: Do you want the RegEx to parse special cases when the day was 1 and not 01?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, still trying to figure this out myself. so apologies if the following creates more questions, but will try an answer it as best as possible... Max I'm playing with regex, but its extracting the date values at certain points in that seq. I'm trying REGEXP to count, then going to see how to work out pulling the values based on an 17 digit value, which will mean the first number is 1-9 for the first 9 days of the month.  If its 18, then I know the fir 2 digits are 10-3x for the remaining days in the month. leftjoin same as above. in a roundabout way i'm using REGEXP

Comment: added an updated sql based on how i think I'll work it.  Looking to get some advice on how i combine the if its 18 digits, then use all the substring associated with it.  Given the starting place changes depending on how many digits exist in the number.

Comment: New Update, I changed this now to separate based on case condition.  This basically separates out the value into separate fields.  Any ideas to concat based on alias field names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct timestamp string representation in Hive is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`.
You do not need to extract all parts separately, then concat to get timestamps. Using regexp_replace you can build correct timestamp using backreferences to capturing groups (in round brackets) in the regexp.

```
with mytable as(--test dataset, use your table instead
select stack(2,
'219872021081000741',
'19872021081000741'
) as AField
)

select
case when length(AField) = 18 
     then timestamp(regexp_replace(AField,'^(\\d{2})\\d{3}(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\d{3}$','$2-$3-$1 $4:$5:00.0'))
     else timestamp(regexp_replace(AField,'^(\\d)\\d{3}(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\d{3}$','$2-$3-0$1 $4:$5:00.0'))
end as result     
from mytable
```

Result:

```
result  
2021-08-21 10:00:00.0
2021-08-01 10:00:00.0
```

Note: `timestamp()` construct here is to demonstrate that string produced is compatible with timestamp data type and is being cast correctly, you can keep it as string if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for that, a lot cleaner than i had for sure.  One question please In the regexp_replace is it possible to add 12 hours/time? Keen to keep it as a string, due to the constraints of a data tool being used to visualize.  Thanks again

Comment: here is a conversion to time and adding 12hours, just struggling to get it back to a string after this...                                                                                                                      
`cast((case when length(Afield) = 18 
then unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(Afield,'^(\\d{2})\\d{3}(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\d{3}$','$2-$3-$1 $4:$5:00.0')) else unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(Afield,'^(\\d)\\d{3}(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\d{3}$','$2-$3-0$1 $4:$5:00.0'))end) + 60*60*12*1000/1000 as TIMESTAMP) as BField`

Comment: unix_timestamp is a seconds (passed from epoch time), you can add to it hours converted to seconds. 12 hrs= 12*60*60. After that convert unix timestamp to timestamp using from_unixtime():  `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(AField,'^(\\d{2})\\d{3}(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\d{3}$','$2-$3-$1 $4:$5:00.0')) + 60*60*12)`, you can add optional format argument to from_unixtime() to get string in format other than default one

Comment: Sometimes you take your chance and ask for help, not knowing what you get.... I'm glad I did and very thankful for your time @leftjoin.  I'm just filling a gap at the moment, and with crazy lockdowns, it can be challenge doing this in the confines of your own home. this has helped me get over a massive hump i've been struggling with, and very thankful!!!